# Visual Studio 2015 crashes on edit and continue

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition, if I put a breakpoint in the code, and and code into an IF statement, I get a fatal error:

> A fatal error has occurred trying to apply code changes and debugging needs to be terminated. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x800004005.

Visual Studio then crashes.

I am not sure what could be causing the problem or where to look. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you definitely set to Debug and not Release mode, also what is the line of code that is causing the error?

Comment: This is because you know... this thing. What is written in the 100th line of the file this_thing.cs of the project I have created right now in my computer.

Comment: Do you use Norton Antivirus?

Comment: In actual fact it is not breaking on any line - this is a Visual Studio error - I am not sure why the down votes? Any line, any code, any break point - VS crashes. Clearly an issue with the IDE, when I find the solution I'll post it to assist the next developer interested in a solution.

Comment: Happens to me as well, when using Edit and Continue in C# (AnyCPU, Debug), it crashes roughly in 50% of cases. Breaking is fine, it crashes when I click "Continue"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, but for me i found a solution. In one of our referenced assemblies we had a * in the assembly version field. So check all referenced assemblies/class libraries.
Open project properties/Application/Assembly Information and type in the Assembly version and File version boxes 1 0 0 0 for example. For me it solves the E&C fatal error.

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem. Strange that VS2012 did not have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar problems in C++ when I've built a solution from a number of projects that had different combinations of /Zi and /ZI flags which specifies the PDB file format (see [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx))